# Let A = {${(x, y) : 0 < x \leq 1, y = \sin (1/x)}$}, B = {${(x, y) : y = 0, 1 < x \leq 0}$}

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Let $A = \{(x, y) : 0 < x \leq 1, y = \sin (1/x)\}$, $B = \{(x, y) : y = 0,  1 < x \leq 0\}$, and let $S = A \cup B$. Prove that $S$ is not arcwise conneceted.

Proof:  Assume that $S$ is arcwise connected, then there exists a continuous function
$g : [0, 1] \rightarrow S$ such that $g(0) = (0, 0)$ and $g(1) = (1, \sin (1))$
I do not know more...

Comment: Think about the "last point" $t$ in $[0,1]$ such that $g(t)$ is in $B$ (defined rigorously by a supremum), and consider the behavior of $g(x)$ as $x$ tends to $t$ from the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof. Suppose $f(t)=(a(t),b(t))$ is a continuous curve defined on $[0,1]$ with $f(t)\in A$ for all $t$ and $f(0)=(0,0)$, $f(1)=(\frac{1}{π},0)$. Then by the intermediate value theorem there is a $0<t_1<1$ so that $a(t_1)=\frac{2}{3π}$. Then there is $0<t_2<t_1$ so that $a(t_2)=\frac{2}{ 5π}$. Continuing, we get a decreasing sequence $t_n$ so that $a(t_n)=\frac{2}{(2n+1)π}$. It follows that $b(t_n)=(−1)^n$. Now since $t_n$ is a decreasing sequence bounded from below it tends to a limit $t_n→c$. Since f is continuous $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)$ must exist. But $\lim_{n\to\infty}b(t_n)$ does not exist.